Solution to the implicit equation expressed as a function
I have the following equation. It involves variables: Delta, n1, n2, n3, and fi. Delta, n1, n2, n3 are real and positive. fi is real too. I would like to have  n1 expressed as a function of Delta, n2, n3 and fi, so that I will be able to use  n1[Delta,n2,n3,fi] in other functions. What needs to be done to this end?
Delta^2 = 
 2*M^2*(n2^2 + 
    0.5*(n1^2 - 2*n1*n2^2*n3^2*Cos[fi] + n2^4*n3^4 + n3^4) + 
        n2*Sqrt[n2^2 + 2*n1*n3^2*Cos[fi] - 2*n2^2*n3^4])


use == for equation and not =. Then use Solve command, screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/19PXygO3.png  and better avoid decimal numbers with exact solvers like Solve, so I changed your 0.5 with 1/2. Mathematica is not like Matlab.

If n1 is a positive real, what does n1[Delta,n2,n3,fi] mean?

Oh, you're just using that to mean "a solution for n1 in terms of ...", right?

Thank you. I have modified my question a little bit. Will your answer hold true in this case as well?

@Nasser Thank you. I have modified my question a little bit. Will your answer hold true in this case as well?

@liricr Yes, a solution for n1 in terms of Delta,n2,n3,fi. This is the most general 4th order equation for n1. I wonder, whether it is possible to have Mathematica give me its root as a function of  Delta,n2,n3,fi..

oh, you want to solve for n1, I thought for Delta. Just change the Solve command to use Solve[eq,n1] in this case instead of Solve[eq,Delta]. Mathematica solves it but you might need assumptions as it says There may be values of the parameters for which some or all solutions are not valid

@Nasser I have already done it but the solution is too lengthy. Is it possible to have it in a compact form? I just need a function n1[Delta,n2,n3,fi] which I can use in other functions.

Since you have solution for n1 (but long) you can always turn it to a function. There are number of topics on this. For example how-do-i-make-a-function-from-a-solution I tried Solve[eq,n1,Reals] but it seems stuck and taking too long. Why not try the current solution as is and see if this works? So what if it is long and complicated?

@Nasser I just need to define n1 as a function of [Delta,n2,n3,fi] which satisfies the equation above. Once this is done, I will need to use   n1=n1[Delta,n2,n3,fi] in  other functions without knowing what it looks like analitically. I do not need an analitical expression for it. if it is possible to define or find  n1=n1[Delta,n2,n3,fi] in a different way?

@Nasser I'll try. Thanks.

@Nasser your code works perfectly well. You provided one solution/root. My equation, being of the 4th order with respect to n1, has four roots/solutions. Is it possible to find the rest? Thanks.

@Nasser Thank you again for a comprehensive answer. You've made my day.

This seems to work
eq = Delta^2 == 
   2*M^2*(n2^2 + 
      1/2*(n1^2 - 2*n1*n2^2*n3^2*Cos[fi] + n2^4*n3^4 + n3^4) + 
      n2*Sqrt[n2^2 + 2*n1*n3^2*Cos[fi] - 2*n2^2*n3^4]);
sol = First@Solve[eq, n1];
n1[Delta_, n2_, M_, n3_, fi_] = n1 /. sol;

And now you can use your function n1
n1[1,2,3,4,5]//N
(*16.7734 + 63.7064 I*)

n1[1, 99, 3, 0, Pi] // N
(*-6.7435*10^-7 - 140.007 I*)

etc..
ps. It might be better/safer to name the function something other than n1.
May be n1F, so the above becomes
 n1F[Delta_, n2_, M_, n3_, fi_] = n1 /. sol;

And now use n1F as the function instead of n1

This equation is a 4th order equation with respect to n1 and has four
solutions. You provided one solution. How can I find the rest?

I used First to pick the first solution. If you want to make function for each solution, you could do
eq = Delta^2 == 
   2*M^2*(n2^2 + 
      1/2*(n1^2 - 2*n1*n2^2*n3^2*Cos[fi] + n2^4*n3^4 + n3^4) + 
      n2*Sqrt[n2^2 + 2*n1*n3^2*Cos[fi] - 2*n2^2*n3^4]);
sol = Solve[eq, n1];
Dimensions[sol]

(*{4,1}*)

So there are 4 solutions. You can now write
n1F[Delta_, n2_, M_, n3_, fi_] = n1 /. sol[[1]];
n2F[Delta_, n2_, M_, n3_, fi_] = n1 /. sol[[2]];
n3F[Delta_, n2_, M_, n3_, fi_] = n1 /. sol[[3]];
n4F[Delta_, n2_, M_, n3_, fi_] = n1 /. sol[[4]];

And now use each function to represent each solution

Reference:  How do I make a function from a solution?

Thank you. It certainly seems to be working. I just need to check this out myself. Thanks.

your code works perfectly well. One more question: This equation is a 4th order equation with respect to n1 and has four solutions. You provided one solution. How can I find the rest?

@neutrino updated for all 4 solutions

This is exactly what I need. Thank you!
